# Remove Single Item in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some trouble with removing an item in my Firebase database on click. When I click the button it deletes everything in that database.

The relevant code is below. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://athenajs.firebaseio.com/favourites";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Intent in = getIntent();

        //         Get JSON values from previous intent
        final String link = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LINK);
        firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("link");
        vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setTag(1);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int status = (Integer) view.getTag();
                if (status == 1) {
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_48dp);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Added to favourites!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    view.setTag(0);

                    firebaseRef.push().setValue(link);
                } else {
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_48dp);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Removed from favourites!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    view.setTag(1);
                    firebaseRef.removeValue(null);
                }


            }

        });
```

Comment: Calling `removeValue()` will remove all data at that location. In your case that seems to be `/links`. If you want to remove specific data under that location, you'll need to do something like `firebaseRef.child("keyOfTheChildToRemove").removeValue()`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your explanation! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using push() you generate a random node.

To delete it you would need to do this:

```
firebaseRef.child(pushId).setValue(null);
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how you want to delete your link since you would be creating a new one every time,, are you trying to remove the last one you created?

Anyway this is how you can save the key and delete that specific item.

```
final String pushId = firebaseRef.push().getKey();
firebaseRef.child(pushId).setValue(link);
```

and then use

```
firebaseRef.child(pushId).setValue(null)
```

to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a brilliant one and it was just what was needed. Cheers! :)

Comment: while showing history and want to delete specific message how to get push id of that message

Answer (score -1):

Remove Item from Firebase Realtime Database in React & Next js

```js
 // firstly create a reference for the database which you want to delete 
 const dbref = ref(db, `Projects/${e.target.value}`)
you can also use UID instead of e.target.value
 // use method Remove Item
        remove(dbref)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```